# PHP/MongoDB Query Assistance

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection with multiple documents. I want to search all the documents, and return each documents instance of a record for 'foo'

Example Collection:

```
Object 1:
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 551993579285313235ebd120
)
[snaps] => Array (
    [0] => ["84062","3","","0-250000","1"]
    [1] => ["84062","4","","0-350000","1"]
)
[zip] => 84057

Object 2:
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 55198dfc928531ea36ebd11f
)
[zip] => testz

Object 3:
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 56a1594e9285319a0a22e15c
)
[snaps] => Array (
    [0] => ["84057","3","","0-250000","1"]
    [1] => ["84020","4","","0-350000","1"]
)
[zip] => 84062
```

I want to return object 1, and 3, but only the "snaps" records, and their values

Current code:

```
try {
                    $conn = new Mongo('localhost');
                    $db = $conn->remo_db1;
                    $c = $db->eudata;
                    $cursor = $c->find(array('snaps'));
                    foreach($cursor as $obj) {
                        echo $obj['snaps'];
                    }

                // disconnect from server
                $conn->close();
                }  catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
                    die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
                } catch (MongoException $e) {
                    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return all objects in the collection with non-empty 'snaps' records and their values:

> $cursor = $c->find( array('snaps'=>array('$nin' => array('
>   ','',null))), array('snaps'=>true));

The first parameter is the query. It returns all objects in the collection that contain  non-empty 'snaps' values.

The second parameter makes it so only the 'snaps' field gets returned. (If you want to return all the fields, simply remove the second parameter).

Hope it helps!

Comment: So if I run this, I get "ArrayArray"... what is the correct way to echo this??

Comment: foreach($cursor as $obj) { print_r($obj); }

Comment: foreach($cursor as $obj) { var_dump($obj); }

Comment: Okay, I thought that was the case. I can open a new question if you want me to, but if I want to utilize the JSON arrays attached to each snaps value, how would I do this? I changed $obj to $obj['snaps'], but I am unsure where to proceed.

Comment: Okay. So I did: foreach ($obj['snaps'] as $snap){ echo $snap . PHP_EOL; }  and now I can see all the JSON arrays in a line. If I wanted to choose JSON array 2, or 3, etc, how would I specify that?

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your time, and patience!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide on how to implement any mongoDb query in php:

http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php